# Grub command runs twice

Tags: linux, grub, dualboot, elementaryos

I am trying to change boot priority and time out in grub. When i run 'update-grub' command, I see the same output twice even for one execution.

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda5@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda5@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

Need some help fixing this.

Also my timeout is 10 seconds. But its waiting for 30 seconds. I saw some answers related to this which i need to work on. Not sure if these are related.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason this runs twice is that you have GRUB installed on your system twice and `update-grub` runs once for each of them.

Specifically, one installation is under `/boot/grub` (which means it's in the root system partition if there is no separate boot partition, or the boot partition if there is one) and the other is under `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub` (which means it's in the ESP/EFI partition). This is also the order they are getting updated, `/boot/grub` is first.

You can discover this by running `` cat `which update-grub` `` to display the contents of whichever `update-grub` script runs when you execute that command (most probably `/usr/sbin/update-grub`).

`ubuntu` in this case comes up because you are on elementaryOS, which is based on Ubuntu and inherits the same boot process and GRUB shims.

It is not yet clear to me in which cases the second `grub` folder gets created, but this is not a problem that needs to be fixed, it seems to be intended behaviour.